# Fixed span element positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am new at javascript and am making a simple page where I have a couple of span elements. The page is supposed to look something like this:

```
Your Name----------------------------------------------Enemy's
Name--------------------------------------------------Your Health:
100/100---------------------------------Enemy's Health: 200/200
```

The "Your Health:" is a span, and "100/100" is another span which has an id so I can change it in javascript. The problem is, if I lower the health value on the left, changing it to 10/100. Since there is less characters, the spans on the right showing the Enemy's health all shift over to the left slightly, since their position is relative to the text on the left.

I have tried adding "`position: fixed`", but that doesn't work. How can I specify an exact fixed position for that element?

Comment: Please read *both* the “*[mcve]*” and “*[ask]*” guidelines. As you’ve not shown your html or any of your attempted css we’re unable to help you in any useful sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at setting the width on the span to ensure anything set to the right does not move based just because of the content of the span.
Also, you will want to set `display: inline-block;` on the span to ensure the spans can sit happily alongside each other.

Overall, I would recommend taking a basic course on CSS, as positioning of elements is a fundamental that should be understood for any front-end styling.

Here is a fiddle showing the fixes I mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/6xcp08zk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Place them in rows and columns to keep them aligned properly.

```
<style>
  .row {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .col50 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
  }
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjEgKP